# Levels in factors of new data does not match?

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am building a decision tree, to try and model a disease phenotype. I'm not too experienced in R so not sure what to do as I've struggled right at the end.

My test data looks like the following:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My prediction data:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The issue is the levels of each is different and so when I type the following I get an error:

```
> predict_data$Phenotype.tree <- predict(tree.train, predict_data)
Error in checkData(oldData, RET) : 
  Levels in factors of new data do not match original data
```

How can I solve?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVWNy.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnB6R.png

Comment: Can you please post your data in a **text** format rather than as images? Images are (1) inaccessible to people with screen readers; (2) un-searchable. (running `str(disease_data)`, `str(predict_data)` will give you output that's easier to cut and paste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* want to do

```r
predict_data <- transform(predict_data, 
    rs139052738 = factor(rs139052738, levels = levels(disease_data$rs139052738))
```

or with tidyverse

```r
predict_data <- (predict_data 
  %>% mutate(across(rs139052738, factor, levels = levels(disease_data$rs139052738)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you do: levels(predict_data$rs139052738) <- levels(disease_data$rs139052738)? which is better?

Comment: modifying the labels directly is dangerous - if there is a difference in ordering you will end up with gibberish

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal reproducible code it is difficult to help.  It seems that the disease_data set has an extra factor (Phenotype) that the predict_data data does not have.

Comment: You're right. Is it okay to simply do this: levels(predict_data$rs139052738) <- levels(disease_data$rs139052738). Or is it frowned upon in ML?

Comment: It's strange that predict_data has one less level compared to disease_data.  Did not predict_data data come from disease_data?  The most reasonable, in my opinion, would be to remove the level of diaease_data that does not have in predict_data.